# selector jquery on table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select an element specific href from a table 'xTable' that create dinamic rows

```
$('#xTable >a').click(function(){

//do something
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `.on` in a specific syntax. See below,

```
$('#xTable').on('click', 'a[href="myhref"]', function(){

    alert(this.href);
});
```

1. The above is called **event-delegation** method. The handler is actually bound to the parent element that exist in dom when this script is executed and then jQuery internally filters and execute the handler only when it finds the matching selector.
2. To select an element with specific href, you need to use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). See above example.